# In Android, can a child activity call a method in the parent activity without closing?

Tags: android

I have an Android app which presents a grid of items in my MainActivity. From that view, I have a child activity that shows options for filtering the items in the main activity. I'm able to update the items in the main activity after closing the child activity, but I want the filtering to happen while the child activity is still open.

Is it possible to trigger a parent activity's method without closing the child activity?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Is it possible to trigger a parent activity's method without closing the child activity?

Yes, send the parent a private intent.

Comment: @Jimtronic: No, its done with `sendBroadcast` and `registerReceiver`.